# No compass displayed on street view through google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

In [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service) on google map API it shows compass on right side of street view.

However it only shows compass if you use **signed_in=true** argument when embedding script i.e.

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
    async defer>
</script>
```

If i remove **signed_in=true** or use **signed_in=false** then compass not showing. Any workaround i don't want to use signed in maps.

Showing compass http://jsfiddle.net/urkwuoto/

Not shows compass http://jsfiddle.net/urkwuoto/1/

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Maps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin?hl=en#changes_to_map_controls), there is a change to user controls depending on whether the user is signed in or not. This is presumably so they can tailor the user's experience appropriately.

I've ran the code locally and noticed that there IS a compass on the non-signed in version, but it's the top left hand side of the screen and is styled differently:

[image: Compass]

Comment: Yep you right but that one is not as good. There's no way to make your own looking similar to signed in_compass?